# QEMU User Mode Networking bypass the VPN on Windows

Tags: networking, vpn, qemu

On Windows, I am using a simple VPN to access content blocked in my country. **When this VPN is running, it seems that all the Internet traffic is going through it: web browser, mail client, CURL, everything... except QEMU!**

Why does the internet traffic of QEMU behave in a different way?

I made some research, and I see that this behavior is specific to QEMU in [User Networking mode](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_(SLIRP)). The Linux Virtual Machine running on QEMU does have access to the Internet, it's able to download and upload files, but it acts just like there is no VPN.

Notes: (my knowledge of network is very limited)

- There is no Virtual Adapter in the Windows settings for QEMU in this mode
- The virtual network is 10.0.2.0/24
- I could not find any way to see the configuration of this virtual network on Windows (if this point make any sense)
- I assume that there should be somewhere a configuration which specify that all the traffic from 10.0.2.0/24 should be routed to a specific Network Card and the same for the traffic entering my Wi-Fi, but I could not find any of these on Windows

**How is internet traffic managed on QEMU User Networking mode?**

PS: this question is not on how to configure bridge networking or how to use the VPN with QEMU, it's really to understand QEMU User Mode networking from the Windows host perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could not find any way to see the configuration of this virtual network on Windows (if this point make any sense)

"User Mode networking" works in a way that means that the host OS is unaware of any networking happening. QEMU uses the "SLiRP" TCP/IP emulator to make the guest think its packets are being forwarded when in reality the emulator process acts like a TCP/UDP *proxy,* with the emulator process establishing TCP connections on behalf of the VM.

With "User Mode" networking, the original packets from 10.0.2.0/24 are never seen by the host; the host thinks that qemu.exe itself (or a helper .exe) is making all of the TCP connections and sending the UDP packets.

(This is also how "NAT Mode" works in VirtualBox, which even uses the exact same SLiRP emulator.)

It is unclear why SLiRP manages to bypass your VPN's default route; it should behave like any other program running on the host (the host is originating the packets, not forwarding them).

> I assume that there should be somewhere a configuration which specify that all the traffic from 10.0.2.0/24 should be routed to a specific Network Card and the same for the traffic entering my Wi-Fi, but I could not find any of these on Windows

If we were talking about a different networking mode and Windows were actually forwarding real packets from 10.0.2.0/24 – you still probably wouldn't find this configuration, as the basic IP routing table only matches on the destination address, not on the source. While certain systems support matching on source (e.g. Linux having SADR for IPv6 as well as PBR "policy-based routing" for both v4/v6), it's rare. (I believe Windows sort of tries to do this automatically in some situations, though.)